# Probability of making it to the playoffs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Toronto Maple Leafs won 30 of 82 games last season (i.e., the 2014-2015 season), giving them a
winning percentage of 37%. If we assume this means the probability of the Leafs winning any given game
is 0.37, then we can predict how they would have done in a playoff series.

Answer the following questions to determine the probability that the Leafs would have won a best of 7
playoff series (i.e., won 4 games) had they made the playoffs last season.

---

a. Rephrase this question in terms of sequences of 0s and 1s. What is the shortest length of a sequence?
What is the longest length of a sequence?

b. Calculate the number of sequences which correspond to the Leafs winning the series. (Note that the
answer is not C(7, 4).

c. Calculate the number of sequences as they relate to this problem. (Note that the answer is not $2^7$ as not all series would last 7 games.

d. Calculate the probability that the Leafs would win the series

---

a) If we let 1 represent a win, and 0 represent a loss, the fastest win is 1 1 1 1, and theres only one way to achieve this. The longest win is 1 0 1 0 1 0 1, and there is C(7,4)=35 ways to achieve this. Thus the longest is 35 sequences, and shortest is 1 sequence.

b) In order to win, they must win 4 games. Thus we have to consider when the games only go to 4, to 5, to 6, and to 7. That is 1 + C(5,4) + C(6,4) + C(7,4) = 56

Are my a) and b) correct? If they are, how would I do part c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (c) we can count the number of ways the Toronto Maple Leafs can win.

Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 4: 1

Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 5: $4\choose3$

Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 6: $5\choose3$

Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 7: $6\choose3$

We add these 4 results together and multiply by 2, accounting for the number of ways the other team can win.

For (d) you would find the probability of each happening:

P(Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 4): $.37^4$

P(Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 5): $4\choose3$($.37^3$)(.63)

P(Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 6): $5\choose3$($.37^3$)($.63^2$)

P(Toronto Maple Leafs wins in 7): $6\choose3$($.37^3$)($.63^3$)

EDIT: (c) I am pretty sure on. (d) maybe not

Comment: Can you see why we do $x\choose3$ rather than $x\choose4$?

Comment: When you say leafs win in 5, why is it $$\binom{4}{3}$$ ... if they win in 5 games, then its $$\binom{5}{4}$$

Comment: Leafs have to win 3  of the first 4 games and then win. There are $4\choose3$ ways this can happen.

Comment: It is hard to explain but if you write down all the possible cases, you will find there are 10 ways to do this.

Comment: After writing down the cases, you will see you are not choosing that they win the fifth game. They must win the fifth game.

Comment: Edit: 4 ways to do this, for the 5 game series. 10 for the 6 game series.

Comment: right .. so we choose that they win the 3 games , but then they MUST win the fourth one, so we arent choosing it, thats why its C(4,3) [choosing that they win 3 of the 4 games] * 1 [they win the 4th game for sure]

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I am not sure about (d) but I am assuming it might be a bit less than .37